# Generating element with php script by the php script

Tags: php, html

I am trying to learn php and now I am stucked with one thing. 
I have the code like this:

```
<select name = "Option1" id ="Option1">
 <option value="0">Option1</option>
  <?php
   include ("db_connect.php");
   $option1 = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM options");
   while($row = $option1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo '<option value = "' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
   }
  ?>
</select>
```

Which is select element with options from database.
But I need 5 of them and copying this piece of code 5 times just doesn't make sense, or am I wrong?

I tried something like this:

```
     function renderSelect()
    {
        for ($a = 0; $a < 5; $a++){
            echo '<select>
                    <option value="0">Option ' . $a . '</option>
                    ' . renderOptions($a) . '
                  </select>';
        }
    }


    function renderOptions(){

   include ("db_connect.php");
   $option1 = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM options");
   while($row = $option1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo '<option value = "' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
   }
  }
```

And then just call the `renderSelect`, but it's not working how expected.

Can you please give me little advice what to do here?

Thanks a lot I appreciate it!

Comment: The first approach looks okay, whats wrong with it?

Comment: The first piece of code is just fine, it generates <select> with options from db. Problem is the second piece of code. I want generate 5 <select> elements with the same options. But it generates Select and options separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use return in your second function. If you echo it in the second function, it will add the echo output to the beginning, where you called the function. You create a String, where you add all your options to it and then return that string.

```
function renderOptions(){

   include ("db_connect.php");
   $option1 = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM options");

   $string = "";
   while($row = $option1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $string .= '<option value = "' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
   }

   return $string;
}
```

And another point to mention, you are calling `renderOption` function and passing `$a` to a function, which takes to parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved it smoothly. Thanks a lot once again!!!